# Why can a dynamically allocated array not infer its size from a list Initializer?

Tags: c++, language-lawyer

Why is:

`new int[]{10,20,30,40,50};`

illegal (at least as of C++14)?, gcc 6.3's error:

> error: too many initializers for ‘int [1]’

Comment: It is what it is. Consider using `std:vector` or `std::array` instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The "why" is rather boring. [[expr.new]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/expr.new#1) demands a complete object type:

> The new-expression attempts to create an object of the type-id or
>   new-type-id to which it is applied. The type of that object is the
>   allocated type. **This type shall be a complete object type**, but not an
>   abstract class type or array thereof.

Since `int[]` is an incomplete object type, it's ill-formed.

Comment: And what constitutes a complete object type?

Comment: @Rotem - Any object type that is not an incomplete object type, as defined by the standard explicitly.

Comment: I think the just begs the followup question "Well, why can't the compiler infer the complete type from the initializer list"? Is there an actual reason that would create ambiguity or was it just arbitrarily omitted?

Comment: @Rotem - The latter. The compiler can certainly infer the type if one uses a placeholder type (`auto`). But that process is described explicitly. The standard can be adjusted to make the OP's code well formed. But that will require someone to write proposal, and the committee to be convinced by it to vote it into C++20.

Comment: @Rotem It can be argued `int arr[] = { ... };` is arbitrarily _added_ instead of the other way round, `arr` is supposed to be declared as type `int[]` after all.

Answer (score 1):

You can write a dedicated helper:

```
template<typename TItem, TItem... VInitialValues> auto
make_array(void) -> ::std::unique_ptr<TItem[]>
{
    return
    (
        ::std::unique_ptr<TItem[]>
        {
            new TItem[sizeof...(VInitialValues)]
            {
                VInitialValues...
            }
        }
    );
}

make_array<int, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50>();
```

or like this:

```
template<typename TItem, typename... TInitialValues> auto
make_array(TInitialValues && ... initial_values) -> ::std::unique_ptr<TItem[]>
{
    return
    (
         ::std::unique_ptr<TItem[]>
         {
             new TItem[sizeof...(TInitialValues)]
             {
                 ::std::forward<TInitialValues>(initial_values)...
             }
         }
    );
}

make_array<int>(10, 20, 30, 40, 50);
```